# No sound in Chrome after conversion to Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: sound, video, google-chrome, flash, 14.10

So I'm a complete and utter noob. Bear this in mind.

I've converted back to Ubuntu after over a year of the misery that is windows 8. I'm running a tiny, craptastic Acer Aspire One, have downloaded Chrome, and now I can't seem to get any sound out of any flash videos I play (youtube, streaming via free tv, etc). I've tried everything listed in the open forums (updating flash, top ten things to do after installing 14.10), but nothing seems to be working. I'm not certain if it's a sound card issue (again, being as green as grass to this particular iteration of Ubuntu), but any help would be greatly appreciated (so that I can go back to watching Downton Abbey and stop clogging up the forum).

Comment: Can you please run a Flash application that's supposed to have sound, run `pactl list` at the same time, and post a link to its output?

Answer (score 0):

Hallo AlphD nd David Foerster,

**i do have the same problem.**

Here is what `pactl list` gives back while running flash application youtube :

Sry but i have to split because pactl list output is to big,

if you have a preffered way to show bigger logs, tell me please and i will edit my

post ;-)

One Add:

I got a real fresh installation of ubuntu 14.10,

other audio works fine, except, browser streaming in chrome and stuff.

Part1 :

---

Modul #0
    Name: module-device-restore
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute state of devices"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #1
    Name: module-stream-restore
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute/device state of streams"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #2
    Name: module-card-restore
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore profile of cards"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #3
    Name: module-augment-properties
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Augment the property sets of streams with additional static information"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #4
    Name: module-switch-on-port-available
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:

Modul #5
    Name: module-alsa-card
    Argument: device_id="2" name="pci-0000_01_00.1" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
    Nutzungszähler: 0
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #6
    Name: module-alsa-card
    Argument: device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_03.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
    Nutzungszähler: 0
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #7
    Name: module-alsa-card
    Argument: device_id="1" name="pci-0000_00_1b.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
    Nutzungszähler: 0
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #8
    Name: module-udev-detect
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Detect available audio hardware and load matching drivers"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #9
    Name: module-bluetooth-policy
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Frédéric Dalleau"
        module.description = "When a bluetooth sink or source is added, load module-loopback"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #10
    Name: module-bluetooth-discover
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Joao Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available bluetooth audio devices and load bluetooth audio drivers"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #11
    Name: module-native-protocol-unix
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Native protocol (UNIX sockets)"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #12
    Name: module-default-device-restore
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the default sink and source"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #13
    Name: module-rescue-streams
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is removed, try to move their streams to the default sink/source"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #14
    Name: module-always-sink
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Hält stets einen Sink geladen, selbst wenn dies ein Null-Sink ist"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #15
    Name: module-intended-roles
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically set device of streams based of intended roles of devices"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #16
    Name: module-suspend-on-idle
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is idle for too long, suspend it"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #17
    Name: module-systemd-login
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Create a client for each login session of this user"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #18
    Name: module-position-event-sounds
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Position event sounds between L and R depending on the position on screen of the widget triggering them."
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #19
    Name: module-filter-heuristics
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Detect when various filters are desirable"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #20
    Name: module-filter-apply
    Argument: 
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Load filter sinks automatically when needed"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #21
    Name: module-x11-publish
    Argument: display=:0
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "X11 credential publisher"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #22
    Name: module-x11-bell
    Argument: display=:0 sample=bell.ogg
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "X11 bell interceptor"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #23
    Name: module-x11-cork-request
    Argument: display=:0
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Synthesize X11 media key events when cork/uncork is requested"
        module.version = "4.0"

Modul #24
    Name: module-x11-xsmp
    Argument: display=:0 session_manager=local/wrigley-Z97X-SOC-Force:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/3370,unix/wrigley-Z97X-SOC-Force:/tmp/.ICE-unix/3370
    Nutzungszähler: k. A.
    Eigenschaften:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "X11 session management"
        module.version = "4.0"

Sink #0
    Status: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1
    Beschreibung: HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
    Besitzermodul: 5
    Stumm: no
    Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
    Verteilung 0,00
    Basislautstärke: 100%
                 0,00 dB
    Quellenüberwachung: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor
    Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
    Merkmale: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Eigenschaften:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 1"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 1"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "7"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0fbb"
        device.string = "hdmi:2,1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo-extra1"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU 71 HDMI/DP"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10de0071,1458367a,00100100"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profile:
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority: 5800, available)
    Aktive Profile: hdmi-output-1
    Formate:
        pcm

Sink #1
    Status: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo
    Beschreibung: Internes Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
    Besitzermodul: 6
    Stumm: no
    Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
    Verteilung 0,00
    Basislautstärke: 100%
                 0,00 dB
    Quellenüberwachung: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor
    Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
    Merkmale: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Eigenschaften:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7914000 irq 51"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0c0c"
        device.product.name = "Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "hdmi:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "Internes Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel Haswell HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:80862807,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profile:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900, not available)
    Aktive Profile: hdmi-output-0
    Formate:
        pcm

Sink #2
    Status: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Beschreibung: Internes Audio Analog Stereo
    Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
    Besitzermodul: 7
    Stumm: no
    Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
    Verteilung 0,00
    Basislautstärke: 100%
                 0,00 dB
    Quellenüberwachung: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
    Merkmale: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Eigenschaften:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC1150 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC1150 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7910000 irq 49"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8ca0"
        device.product.name = "9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Internes Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC1150"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0900,1458a172,00100001"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profile:
        analog-output: Analoge Ausgabe (priority: 9900)
        analog-output-headphones: Analoge Kopfhörer (priority: 9000, not available)
    Aktive Profile: analog-output
    Formate:
        pcm

Quelle #0
    Status: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1.monitor
    Beschreibung: Monitor of HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
    Besitzer-Modul: 5
    Stumm: no
    Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
            Verteilung 0,00
    Basis-Lautstärke: 100%
                 0,00 dB
    Sink-Monitor: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra1
    Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Eigenschaften:
        device.description = "Monitor of HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0fbb"
        device.string = "2"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formate:
        pcm

Quelle #1
    Status: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor
    Beschreibung: Monitor of Internes Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
    Besitzer-Modul: 6
    Stumm: no
    Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
            Verteilung 0,00
    Basis-Lautstärke: 100%
                 0,00 dB
    Sink-Monitor: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo
    Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Eigenschaften:
        device.description = "Monitor of Internes Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7914000 irq 51"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0c0c"
        device.product.name = "Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formate:
        pcm

Quelle #2
    Status: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
    Beschreibung: Monitor of Internes Audio Analog Stereo
    Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
    Besitzer-Modul: 7
    Stumm: no
    Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
            Verteilung 0,00
    Basis-Lautstärke: 100%
                 0,00 dB
    Sink-Monitor: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Eigenschaften:
        device.description = "Monitor of Internes Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7910000 irq 49"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8ca0"
        device.product.name = "9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "1"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formate:
        pcm

---

I really appreciate any help guys!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Part 2 :

Quelle #3
    Status: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Beschreibung: Internes Audio Analog Stereo
    Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
    Besitzer-Modul: 7
    Stumm: no
    Lautstärke: 0:  16% 1:  16%
            0: -48,00 dB 1: -48,00 dB
            Verteilung 0,00
    Basis-Lautstärke:  10%
                 -60,00 dB
    Sink-Monitor: k. A.
    Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Eigenschaften:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC1150 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC1150 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7910000 irq 49"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8ca0"
        device.product.name = "9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Internes Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC1150"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0900,1458a172,00100001"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profile:
        analog-input-microphone-front: Mikrofon vorne (priority: 8500, not available)
        analog-input-microphone-rear: Mikrofon hinten (priority: 8200, not available)
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100, not available)
    Aktive Profile: analog-input-linein
    Formate:
        pcm

Client #0
    Treiber: module-systemd-login.c
    Owner-Modul: 17
    Eigenschaften:
        application.name = "Login Session c2"
        systemd-login.session = "c2"

Client #1
    Treiber: protocol-native.c
    Owner-Modul: 11
    Eigenschaften:
        application.name = "Ubuntu Audio Settings"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.id = "com.canonical.settings.sound"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = "0.1"
        application.process.id = "3424"
        application.process.user = "wrigley"
        application.process.host = "wrigley-Z97X-SOC-Force"
        application.process.binary = "indicator-sound-service"
        application.language = "de_DE.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "813e56ef1c4f171bda95b46b5448007c"
        application.process.session_id = "c2"

Client #2
    Treiber: protocol-native.c
    Owner-Modul: 11
    Eigenschaften:
        application.name = "GNOME Volume Control Media Keys"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = "1.0"
        application.process.id = "3362"
        application.process.user = "wrigley"
        application.process.host = "wrigley-Z97X-SOC-Force"
        application.process.binary = "unity-settings-daemon"
        application.language = "de_DE.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "813e56ef1c4f171bda95b46b5448007c"
        application.process.session_id = "c2"

Client #7
    Treiber: module-x11-xsmp.c
    Owner-Modul: 24
    Eigenschaften:
        application.name = "XSMP Session on gnome-session as 10403b3384fb18ce4c142174939988793600000033700049"
        xsmp.vendor = "gnome-session"
        xsmp.client.id = "10403b3384fb18ce4c142174939988793600000033700049"

Client #16
    Treiber: protocol-native.c
    Owner-Modul: 11
    Eigenschaften:
        application.name = "pactl"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "28"
        application.process.id = "16886"
        application.process.user = "wrigley"
        application.process.host = "wrigley-Z97X-SOC-Force"
        application.process.binary = "pactl"
        application.language = "de_DE.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "813e56ef1c4f171bda95b46b5448007c"
        application.process.session_id = "c2"

Karte #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1
    Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner-Modul: 5
    Eigenschaften:
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card2"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0fbb"
        device.string = "2"
        device.description = "HDA NVidia"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profile:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 5400)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 300)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 5200)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 5200)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 100)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 5200)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 100)
        off: Aus (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority. 0)
    Aktive Profile: output:hdmi-stereo-extra1
    Profile:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Eigenschaften:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Eigenschaften:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "BenQ GL2450H
"
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: output:hdmi-stereo-extra1
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Eigenschaften:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Eigenschaften:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3

Karte #1
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0
    Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner-Modul: 6
    Eigenschaften:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7914000 irq 51"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0c0c"
        device.product.name = "Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Internes Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profile:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 5400)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 300)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 5200)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 100)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 5200)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 100)
        off: Aus (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority. 0)
    Aktive Profile: output:hdmi-stereo
    Profile:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Eigenschaften:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Eigenschaften:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Eigenschaften:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2

Karte #2
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0
    Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner-Modul: 7
    Eigenschaften:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7910000 irq 49"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "8ca0"
        device.product.name = "9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Internes Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profile:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Eingang (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority. 60)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 6000)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority. 6060)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 700)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Ausgang + Analog Stereo Eingang (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority. 760)
        output:analog-surround-41: Analog Surround 4.1 Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 800)
        output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Ausgang + Analog Stereo Eingang (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority. 860)
        output:analog-surround-50: Analog Surround 5.0 Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 700)
        output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Ausgang + Analog Stereo Eingang (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority. 760)
        output:analog-surround-51: Analog Surround 5.1 Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 800)
        output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Ausgang + Analog Stereo Eingang (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority. 860)
        output:analog-surround-71: Analog Surround 7.1 Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 700)
        output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 7.1 Ausgang + Analog Stereo Eingang (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority. 760)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Ausgang (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority. 5500)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Ausgang + Analog Stereo Eingang (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority. 5560)
        off: Aus (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority. 0)
    Aktive Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
    Profile:
        analog-input-microphone-front: Mikrofon vorne (priority: 8500, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Eigenschaften:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-microphone-rear: Mikrofon hinten (priority: 8200, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Eigenschaften:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output: Analoge Ausgabe (priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Analoge Kopfhörer (priority: 9000, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Eigenschaften:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        iec958-stereo-output: Digitaler Ausgang (S/PDIF) (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Teil des Profils/der Profile: output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo